# how to let two cards in the bottom fill the full height of screen (Quasar framework)

Tags: html, vue.js, quasar

I used the Quasar framework to make a structure like the photo below. My question is how to let two cards in the bottom fill the full height of the screen except the top one. I tried many methods were not work. Who can tell me how to make it. Thank you.

---

```
<q-page>
<!-- card on top -->
<q-card
  class="q-mx-xs q-mt-xs"
  style="border-radius: 8px;"
>
 </q-card>
<div class="windowsheight q-mx-none q-mt-xs row item-start q-gutter-none content-around">
  <!-- card on left bottom with full height -->
  <div class="windowsheight col-12 col-md-4">
    <q-card class="full-height q-ma-xs q-gutter-xs">
    </q-card>
  </div>
  <!-- card on right bottom with full height -->
  <div class="windowsheight col-12 col-md-8">
    <q-card class="full-height q-ma-xs q-gutter-xs">
    </q-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

structure see here:

[image]

Comment: Could you show an example of how it should look? Or is the above graphic how you want it to look?

Comment: Yes, I want my app looks like my graphic. I can draw it. My question is how to let two cards on the bottom fill the full height of screen except the top one. I tried many methods were not work. Two cards on the bottom can not cover the full height. I tried many methods were not work.

Comment: What have you tried? What does it look like now? Please edit your question.

Comment: I used the code above, then the height of two cards on the bottom just match their content. So I can see the gap on the screen bottom. I just want the height of two cards on the bottom= window screen - height of the card on the top.

Comment: I had a problem that was similar to yours, and I finally solved it using CSS calculation functions. You can try `calc(100vh - topHeight)`